# QFT $\sigma$-model - Commutator of Pauli and Gamma matrices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, commutator, lie-algebra, dirac-matrices

To give some contest, I'm working on a $\sigma$-model given by the Lagrangian

$$L = \bar\psi i \partial_\mu\gamma^\mu \psi - g\bar\psi (\sigma + i\vec\pi \cdot \vec\tau \gamma^5)\psi + \frac{1}2(\partial_\mu \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma + \partial_\mu\vec\pi \cdot\partial^\mu\vec\pi) + V(\sigma^2 + \pi^2)$$

I omit the structure of the potential since it's irrelevant to my question; the point is that $\psi$ is a Dirac field, $\sigma$, $\vec \pi$ are respectively a scalar field and a 3-vector field, while $\tau ^a$ is the $a$-th Pauli matrix. What I understand is that $\tau^a$ acts as a 2x2 matrix on $\psi$, i.e. mixing the left and the right component of the Dirac spinor, but it leaves untouched the components of the left/right Weyl spinor. To give and example, I'm thinking that

$$\tau^1 \psi = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \psi_R \\ \psi_L \end{bmatrix} $$

and that (here I'm writing only $\psi_L$ but the same structure clearly holds for $\psi_R$) $$\psi_{L} = \begin{bmatrix} \xi_{L_1} \\ \xi_{L_2} \end{bmatrix} $$

My objective is computing the vectorial 4-current, associated to a symmetry (which is more explicit if I re-define the Lagrangian through the fields $\Sigma = \sigma + i\vec\pi \cdot \vec \tau$ and $\psi_{L/R} = \frac{1}2 (1 \mp \gamma^5) \psi$); but to rearrange the current I bump into a controversy. Let me show it. One of the contribution to the current is

$$\bar\psi_{L} i \gamma^\mu \frac{i}2 \tau^a \psi_L + \bar\psi_{R} i \gamma^\mu \frac{i}2 \tau^a \psi_R =  \\ 
\frac{1}2 \psi^\dagger(1-\gamma^5)\gamma^0 i \gamma^\mu \frac{i}2 \tau^a \frac{1}2 (1 - \gamma^5) \psi + \frac{1}2 \psi^\dagger(1+\gamma^5)\gamma^0 i \gamma^\mu \frac{i}2 \tau^a \frac{1}2 (1 + \gamma^5) \psi = \\
-\frac{1}8 \bar\psi \gamma^\mu [(1-\gamma^5) \tau^a (1- \gamma^5) + (1+\gamma^5) \tau^a (1+ \gamma^5)]\psi = \\
-\frac{1}4 \bar\psi \gamma^\mu [\tau^a + \gamma^5 \tau^a \gamma^5] \psi $$

Now, the expected result (given for example in the problem 5.17 in Radovanovich - Problem Book Quantum Field Theory) would be $-\frac{1}2 \bar\psi \gamma^\mu \tau^a \psi $, which could be obtained if $[\tau^a, \gamma^5] = 0$.

My question: how could these matrices commute? Aren't they acting on the same space, more explicitly aren't they matrices on the Dirac spinor components?

Comment: $\tau^a$ and $\gamma^\mu$ act on different vector spaces so they commute.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Let me rephrase my question: it is clear that they have to act on different spaces, but I cannot  see why. If the Pauli matrices mix the components, and so do the Gamma matrices, why am I allowed to consider them as acting on different spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dramatically misreading the formalism setup, probably victimized by the use of Pauli matrices in explaining the structure of the [Weyl representation of γ matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_(chiral)_basis_(alternate_form)). You may use Pauli matrices in a direct product structure when confusion can be prevented.

In particular, you are working in an 8-dimensional direct product space, not a 4-dimensional one. Let me first supplant the implicit indices which you skipped to get into this trouble.

The *ψ*s are 8-vectors, $\psi^i_\alpha$, where the isospin indices *i* take values 1,2, and are acted upon the $\tau^a_{ij}$ matrices; while the *α* s are the four Dirac spinor indices, and are acted upon by all $\gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta}$ matrices. So the two types of indices live in distinct Cartesian factor vector spaces, yielding 8-dimensional vectors, $2\times 4$, and acted upon by the 8×8  matrices $\tau^a \otimes \gamma^\mu$. (I hope you appreciate the bizarre bogus actions of the Pauli matrices you wrote are  worse than meaningless.)

Crucially, note the *a*s acting on the pseudoscalar pions have nothing to do with spacelike spacetime indices, possibly the source of your conflation of Pauli matrices used for *two purposes* here.

Moreover, the issue of "ordering" *τ*s and *γ*s doesn't even arise, since they are in different factor spaces of your direct product:  *τ*s  act on isospin apples and *γ*s on spinor oranges.

Write the explicit indices in your spinors and see that you may reorder transpose the apples and the oranges without ambiguity or obstruction.

Comment: I think you couldn't be clearer. My problem was that, even if I had all the indices explicited, I couldn't understand why those indices were substancially different (basically I was still trying matrix product). That's because isospin didn't come across my mind at all. And of course this has nothing to do with R/L spin decomposition (which makes my post so embarassing) but indeed acts on a different space. A sincere thank you.